# Do You ever do a pull request to your own Forked repo?

Tags: git, github, open-source

I am a bit of a beginner to Github. I just want to make sure my understanding of the Github workflow is correct.

Suppose I found a repo called `cool_repo`. I have an idea for a feature, so I fork it to `my_username:cool_repo`. Then I clone it on my personal computer. I then make a new branch `cool_new_feature`, code the new feature, and commit then push this code into the `cool_new_feature` on my fork. Finally I do a pull request (merge) to upstream's (i.e. `cool_repo`) `master` branch and they would accept/decline my merge. **Now my question is, do I ever update the `master` branch in `my_username:cool_repo` with my own work? Or is it just simply there to pull from `cool_repo` whenever there is a new feature added?**

Answer (score 0):

It is totally up to you to come up with an internal branching strategy for your forked repo. If you are attempting more than one change on cool_repo and you would like to work on different branches within your fork, then it makes sense to merge them to master and raise a Pull Request on the upstream.

Either way, it is good practice to keep master up to date with upstream code and also merge your work into master to keep it in sync (with stable-working code)

If you generally want to know about branching strategy in git, then this is a good read [A successful Git branching model](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/)